# How do I access these Elements of a class using Iterator?

Tags: java

I have two classes: `Question` and `Answers`. The `Answer` class has its own attributes. I passed 2 Lists of arguments to `Answers` using Constructor-Injection (Spring framework).

I want to iterate to display only the id of the Answer attribute. Is that possible ?

```
package Question.Answer;

public class Answers {
String id;
String name;
String by;
     public Answers(String id,String name,String by) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.by = by;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "id:"+id+"name:"+name+"Posted by"+by;
    }
}
```

Question Class

```
package Question.Answer;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
public class Question {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private List<Answers> answers;
    public Question(String name,String id,List<Answers> answers) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.answers = answers;
    }
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Name:\t"+name+"\nid:\t"+id);
        Iterator itr = answers.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
            System.out.print("\n"+itr.next());
    }
}
```

The present code displays every attribute in answer class ie 
`id`, `name`, `postedby`.

Comment: It is using your toString method. Either change toString, or change your print statement to just print the id. Eg. `System.out.print("\n" + itr.next().id`

Comment: Works like a charm thanks.

Answer (score 3):

On the place where you make Iterator

```
Iterator itr = answers.iterator();
```

please add type like this:

```
Iterator<Answers> itr = answers.iterator();
```

Now when you call itr.next() it will give you Answers object. Just to be more clear add this rows on the place of

```
System.out.print("\n"+itr.next());
```

Please replace with:

```
Answers answer = itr.next();
System.out.print("\n" + answer.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You desire can be fulfilled by this:

1.Change your `toString` method to just return `id`;

2.Print only `id` in collection:

```
Iterator<Answer> itr = answers.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print("\n"+itr.next().id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [enhanced for loops](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/using-enhanced-for-loops-with-your-classes) to make your code clearer and more easily maintainable:

```
for (Answers answer : answers) {
    System.out.print("\n" + answer.id);
}
```

If you let `System.out.print("\n" + answer);`, the `toString()` of your class `Answers` (which includes all fields) will be called.
You can also change `Answers.toString()` to only include the id.

Comment: Despite the title the iteration is no problem here but in the way the object is ouputted. Also the question especially focuses on the Iterator object.

Comment: There is no reason to burden the code with extra objects and lines of code when there is already a perfect built-in functionality to do _exactly_ what the user wants.